# Unable to register AWS Batch Job Definition with Secrets Manager secret

Tags: aws-secrets-manager, aws-batch

When I attempt to register an AWS Batch job definition with secrets from AWS Secrets Manager (specifying an execution role and secrets per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html))

```
aws batch register-job-definition \
    --job-definition-name poc_secrets_job \
    --region us-east-2 \
    --type container \
    --container-properties '{
  "image": "busybox",
  "vcpus": 1,
  "memory": 120,
  "command": [
    "echo",
    "Hello world"
  ],
  "executionRoleArn":  "arn:aws:iam::<AWS-ACCOUNT-ID>:role/<EXECUTION-ROLE-NAME>",
  "jobRoleArn":  "arn:aws:iam::<AWS-ACCOUNT-ID>:role/<EXECUTION-ROLE-NAME>",
  "secrets": [{"name": "TEST_SECRET", "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:<AWS-ACCOUNT-ID>:secret:<SECRET-NAME>"}]
}'
```

I get the error message:

> Parameter validation failed:

> Unknown parameter in containerProperties: "secrets", must be one of: image, vcpus, memory, command, jobRoleArn, volumes, environment, mountPoints, readonlyRootFilesystem, privileged, ulimits, user, instanceType, resourceRequirements, linuxParameters

> Unknown parameter in containerProperties: "executionRoleArn", must be one of: image, vcpus, memory, command, jobRoleArn, volumes, environment, mountPoints, readonlyRootFilesystem, privileged, ulimits, user, instanceType, resourceRequirements, linuxParameters

I've also been unable to get this to work with Terraform's [aws_batch_job_definition resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/batch_job_definition).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was on an older version of the `aws` cli tool.  I upgraded to the latest version 2 (2.1.21) and this now works.